# Run portlet from localhost

Tags: java, portlet, jdeveloper, weblogic11g, oracleportal

I've inherited a couple of Java applications designed to work as portlets, a tech nobody in the company is familiar with, together with a PC with all the stuff already configured.

With current set up, development works by having a test page in Oracle Portal production server that loads the portlet from my PC's IP address. That's far from ideal for several reasons, the main one being that only some parts of the application run via portlet, so in order to share session data I need hacks that involve passing session ID around in the URL.

Is there a way to run the complete application, porlet included, from the local WebLogic server bundled with JDeveloper 11g?

Comment: "Is there a way?" I'd sure expect "yes" to be the answer there. But given the level of detail we know (you have an installation of stuff), I can't imagine this to lead to a productive answer. Oracle Portal can be installed on more than one computer, I'm not sure how they handle developer licenses (which _might_ be the root cause for this way of installing it: Avoiding yet another license to be bought. But notice, I'm conspiring here)

Comment: @OlafKock Sorry for the lack of detail but if knew for sure what my current tool can do and what additional tools I need, I wouldn't probably need to ask in the first place ;-) Should I understand from your comment that JDeveloper doesn't allow it and I need to install a local copy of Oracle Portal?

Comment: That, I can't say. I'm coming from the Liferay world - and in order to run something on Liferay, you just run it on Liferay - on whatever development computer you're on. There's typically more than the portlet API that you'll need in such an application. I've been teasing in my comment on your yes/no question: It's software, can run on any number of computers, so the answer is certainly yes. But that's probably not what you're looking for. The "how" depends on the structure of your code: To run a portlet, you most likely need a portal.